# How to make multidimensional array in blade and send it to controller using laravel 5.5+

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I am making nested array in .blade.php and sending it to controller.php , but i am not receiving nested array in controller.php
So i want nested array like:

"itemized" => array:1 [▼ 0 => "[▼ 0=>["small",10,"Recurring"], ▼ 1=>["medium",0,"Recurring"], ▼ 2=>["large",0,"Recurring"], ▼ 3=>["oversize",0,"Recurring"]]" ]

**.blade.php**

```
@php
                $itemized_arr = array
                (
                    array("small",$job->small_items*$box[0]->price,'Recurring'),
                    array("medium",$job->medium_items*$box[1]->price,'Recurring'),
                    array("large",$job->large_items*$box[2]->price,'Recurring'),
                    array("oversize",$job->oversize_items*$box[3]->price,'Recurring'),
                );
            @endphp

            <input type="hidden" name="itemized[]" value="{{ json_encode($itemized_arr, TRUE) }}">
```

**controller.php**

this is what i am receiving in controller.php by

*dd($request->all();*

"itemized" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "[["small",10,"Recurring"],["medium",0,"Recurring"],["large",0,"Recurring"],["oversize",0,"Recurring"]]"
  ]

Comment: can i know WHY "I am making nested array in .blade.php and sending it to controller.php" something you doing conceptually wrong here

Comment: Please mention how to trying to extract data from this array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a single element then you don't need multiple things while creating the html element. So remove the [] from the element name.

Try this

**blade.php**

```
@php

$itemized_arr = array
(
    array("small",$job->small_items*$box[0]->price,'Recurring'),
    array("medium",$job->medium_items*$box[1]->price,'Recurring'),
    array("large",$job->large_items*$box[2]->price,'Recurring'),
    array("oversize",$job->oversize_items*$box[3]->price,'Recurring'),
);

@endphp

<input type="hidden" name="itemized" value="{{ json_encode($itemized_arr, TRUE) }}">
```

and in the controller the type of the $input['itemized'] is string(a JSON string). all you have to do now is decode the string using json_decode function

**controller.php**

```
$input = $request->all(); 
$itemized = json_decode($input['itemized']);
```

Comment: Welcome. Good luck for your project.